# I can't access the data in my axios post request

Tags: javascript, python, python-requests, axios

I'm trying to access the data I stored in localStorage so I can use it in my Python route.

Here's my axios request:

```
if ($('.box.genre').length === $('.box.genre.completed').length) {
    async function getScore() {
      let score = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("score"));
      const response = await axios.post(
        `${BASE_URL}/game-over`, { "score": score}, {
          headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
          }
        }).then(response =>
          localStorage.getItem("score", response.data.score));
      console.log('Your score was: ', response);
     window.location = "/game-over";
    }
    getScore();  
  }
```

When I console log the response I'm able to see the score. My Python code doesn't seem to be working. I'm unable to get the data. I get an AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'content'.

Here's my Python:

```
@app.route('/game-over', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def game_over():

  if CURR_USER_KEY in session:
    user = User.query.get(session[CURR_USER_KEY])

  response = request.json()
  data = json.loads(response.content)
  score = data['score']

  user.high_score = score
  db.session.commit()

  high_score = user.high_score
  name = user.username

  return render_template('endgame.html', name=name, high_score=high_score)
```

I'm just trying to get the score from axios so I can update my SQL table. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: I don't understand why you use `requests`. If `axios` sends request with `score` (in JSON format) to `/game-over` then `game_over()` should use `Flask.response.json() ` to get it. And `game_over()` should send answer to `axios`  (in JSON format) using `return jsoinify({'score': score})` (instead of `return render_template(...)`). Code `requests.get()` doesn't sends back to web browser and axios but it sends request to other URL on server and it means other function in Flask on server.

Comment: Using request.json() still gives me the NoneType error. Also if I don't render my template how will my page load? I want to show the score and username on my final page.

Comment: use two functions - one to render page when browser visit `http://example.com/game-over` and second to work with `axios.post("/game-over", ...)` but it may need new URL - ie. `/game-over-ajax`. OR in `def game_over()` use `if/else` to check if it is normal request or ajax and send back HTML (for normal request) or JSON data (for ajax request)

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems in your code.

**First**: If you want to set an item in local storage you must use `setItem` instead `getItem`

**Second**: When you use an async function, You do not need to use `.then`

```
async function getScore()
 const response = await axios.post(
  `${BASE_URL}/game-over`,
  { 'score': score },
  { headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' }
 })

 if (response) {
  localStorage.setItem('score', response.data.score)
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a try when I get home in a few hours.

Comment: It didn't work. I've already set the score to local storage earlier in my code. I'm trying to retrieve it. I think the problem is in my Python code. I don't know which method to use to retrieve the score from the axios response.